# How to get the post publish date outside the loop?

Tags: database, date

I need to pull out the post publish date in order to make the post post auto expire. The thing is I can't get the right publish date.

Here is my code:

```
 global $wpdb;

$post_ids = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status ='publish'" );

foreach($post_ids as $id){

      $postdate = get_the_date("Y-m-d",$id ); //here is what I can figure out
       .......
      ......etc
}
```

When I echo the $postdate, it come out with a wrong date. Not the date that exist in the wp_posts table.

How can I get the date properly?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`get_the_date` must be used inside the Loop. For outside the loop use [`get_the_time`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_the_time).

```
$posts = get_posts(array('numberposts'=>-1)); //Get all published posts
foreach ($posts as $post){
    echo get_the_time('Y-m-d', $post->ID); //Echos date in Y-m-d format.
}
```

Consider replacing `'Y-m-d'` in this example with `get_option('date_format')` as this will display the date as per your date format setting in wp-admin.

Comment: I tried get_the_time as well, but still give me the wrong date.

Comment: And you give pass the post ID to it? `get_the_time` is the correct function to use here.

Comment: Also - you shouldn't be using a custom SQL query here. Use [`get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) and then if you want to extract just the IDs, use [`wp_list_pluck`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck)

Comment: I am doing something to update the post_status based on the publish date, is there any other way to update the status? So far, SQL query seem to easiest way to me.

Comment: See edits - you should almost never need to query the database directly.

Comment: I see you point. I tried it, and it works perfectly. But I like to know why I shouldn't use query the database directly? For security sake?

Comment: Security (kind of), performance (probably) but mainly code simplicity and forward-compatibility - i.e. using the provided API (`get_post`) in this case.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I was not aware that could pass an ID> When using get_posts there is no way to display the post date without it.

Comment: @StephenHarris while this function gets the date the post was created, is it possible to get the modified date/time outside the loop?

Comment: @Anagio - see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95769/get-date-of-last-update-outside-of-loop/115044#115044

Comment: According to the Codex, `get_the_time` tag must be used within The Loop. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_time

Comment: @MaorBarazany, seems codex is wrong, see source: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L1497

Comment: You linked to get_post_time rather than get_the_time, which is rather confusing.  They accomplish the same thing but have different args.  Any chance you could fix the link?  Thanks!

Comment: @DavidHobs Fixed :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [get_post()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post/) or [get_post_field()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_field/) for this, both work outside the loop.

```
$post_object = get_post($id);
$post_date = date( 'F jS, Y', strtotime( $post_object->post_date ) );
```

A full list of values returned by get_post:

```
WP_Post Object
(
    [ID] =>
    [post_author] =>
    [post_date] => 
    [post_date_gmt] => 
    [post_content] => 
    [post_title] => 
    [post_excerpt] => 
    [post_status] =>
    [comment_status] =>
    [ping_status] => 
    [post_password] => 
    [post_name] =>
    [to_ping] => 
    [pinged] => 
    [post_modified] => 
    [post_modified_gmt] =>
    [post_content_filtered] => 
    [post_parent] => 
    [guid] => 
    [menu_order] =>
    [post_type] =>
    [post_mime_type] => 
    [comment_count] =>
    [filter] =>
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Some Modern soultions

Solution One

```
<?php echo get_the_date('j F Y', get_the_ID()) ?>
```

Solution Two

```
<?php the_time(get_option('date_format')) ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

try like this

```
$getPosts = $wpdb->get_results( 
"
    SELECT ID, post_date,post_title
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    WHERE post_status = 'publish' 
        AND post_type = 'post'
        ORDER BY ID ASC
    "
);

foreach ( $getPosts as $myPost ) {
    $id = $myPost->post_date;
    echo $myPost->ID.' | '. $myPost->post_title.' | '. get_the_date("Y-m-d",$id ).'<br />';
}
```

edit

**[get_the_time](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_time)**  Returns the time of the current post for use in PHP. It does not display the time. To display the time of a post, use the_time(). This tag must be used within The Loop.

**[get_the_date](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_date)** The get_the_date template tag retrieves the date the current $post was written. Unlike the_date() this tag will always return the date. Modify output with 'get_the_date' filter.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Please merge your answers.

Comment: show me how to merge, please?

Comment: Edit the first answer and copy the code from the second into it. Then delete the second.

Comment: I tried your codes, and I can get the value from get_the_time, not get_the_date.