# Get date of last update outside of loop

Tags: loop, date, date-time

I'm trying to figure out how to display the date that a post was last updated outside of the loop. I'm able to display the published date using `get_the_time()` but there doesn't seem to be a "loopless" function to get the date of the last update.

Does anyone know hot to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is unclear if you are looking for the last updated post or for the last updated date for some particular post. The answer by @PatJ assumes the former. To do the latter:

```
$qry = new WP_Query(array('p'=>1));
var_dump($qry->posts[0]->post_modified);
```

Or...

```
$date = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT post_modified FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE ID = 1");
var_dump($date);
```

Of course you need to change the post ID to match the post you are looking for.

Answer (score 8):

According to [the Codex page for `get_the_time()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_time), it needs to be used in The Loop.  The difference between [`the_time()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_time) and [`get_the_time()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_time) is that the former [`echo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)es the date, and the latter returns it.

There are a couple functions that do what I think you're looking for -- get the last updated date and time for a post:  [`get_the_modified_time()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_modified_date) and [`get_the_modified_date()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_modified_date).  It looks like they too need to be used in [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).

Here's one way to get the updated date of the most recent post in your site:

```
<?php
     $args = array(
        'orderby'     => 'post_modified',
        'numberposts' => 1,
    );
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    if( have_posts() ) {
        while( have_posts() ) {
            the_post();
            $last_update = get_the_modified_date();
        }
    }
    echo( "Last modified on $last_update." );
?>
```

If you're sure you need to be outside of any Loops, you can always use [`$wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class):

```
<?php
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = "SELECT post_modified
            FROM $wpdb->posts
            WHERE post_type='post'
            AND post_status='publish'
            ORDER BY post_modified DESC
            LIMIT 1";
    $last_update = $wpdb->get_var( $sql );
    echo( "Last updated $last_update." );
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. The 2nd code block is more what I'm looking for.

Comment: Glad you got your answer.

Answer (score 2):

A late addition, but the following snippet can be modified to use most functions outside of the loop:

```
/**
 * Returns a post's modified date, formatted according to $format.
 * @uses the_modified_time()
 *
 * @param int $post_id Post ID.
 * @param string $format Date format Default: "F j, Y".
 */
function wpse95769_modified_date_by_id( $post_id = 0, $format = "F j, Y" ){
    global $post;
    $post = &get_post( $post_id );
    setup_postdata( $post );

    $modified_time = get_the_modified_time( $format );

    wp_reset_postdata( $post );

    return $modified_time;
}
```

Comment: Ths is interesting; so how would one turn this into a shortcode to put into the page editor to show the last modified date of a page? I tried turning it into a shortcode with no luck `function last_modified_shortcode() {

function wpse95769_modified_date_by_id( $page_id = 0, $format = "F j, Y" ){
    global $page;
    $page = &get_post( $page_id );
    setup_postdata( $page );

    $modified_time = get_the_modified_time( $format );

    wp_reset_postdata( $page );

    return $modified_time;
}
}
add_shortcode( 'last_modifed', 'last_modifed_shortcode' );'

Answer (score 1):

Another late addition, which may be helpful to know if anyone is looking. You can use these two functions to get the post date and modified date outside the loop.

```
<?php get_post_time( $d, $gmt, $post, $translate ); ?>
```

and

```
<?php get_post_modified_time( $d, $gmt, $post, $translate ); ?>
```

You can read more about these two functions in the codex.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_post_time
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_modified_time

Answer (score 1):

It may not be clear from previous answers, but get_post_time() and get_post_modified_time() can be given a post object or post ID. So, to get the published and modified dates by post ID outside the loop:

```
$published_time = get_post_time( $date_fmt, null, $post_id );
$modified_time = get_post_modified_time( $date_fmt, null, $post_id );
```

js.

Answer (score 0):

What about the [`get_lastpostmodified( $timezone )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_lastpostmodified) function?

Comment: This returns the date when the last post has been modified. So this function is not post-specific but blog-specific - and hence not what was asked for.

Comment: How would you tell `get_lastpostmodified` which post you want?